# Open a new terminal, monitor it and execute a script

Tags: shell-script, scripting, gnome-terminal, typescript

I have a script that I want to monitor its results and write them to a log file. I run the following:

`gnome-terminal -x bash -c "script logfile.log; ssh user@IP"`

But this command execute first the first command and after that the 2nd. Can I do them like in series without any input from me? to execute first the script command to write the logfile I want and after that the ssh without I need to do something else?

I tried the way it is and it doesn't do what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried having `script` be the outer part

```
gnome-terminal -x script -c "ssh user@IP" logfile.log
```

Comment: and what if i want to use something like | tee logfile.log OR > logfile.log

Comment: Well, you could still put the `bash -c` part there if you want and have `script -c` be part of what it executes

Comment: thanks for the help. that worked perfect! Now, i try to run multiple tabs for multiple ssh and it doesn't work. I try: `gnome-terminal --working-directory=$PATH --tab-with-profile=$IP1 -x script -c "ssh user1@IP1" $PATH_REPORT/IP1.log --tab-with-profile=$IP2 -x script -c "ssh user@IP2" $PATH_REPORT/IP2.log`

Comment: @Kostas Try quoting the entire command and using `-e` instead of `-x` like: `gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=$IP1 -e "script -c 'ssh user@$IP1' $PATH_REPORT/IP1.log" --tab-with-profile=$IP2 -e "...` and if that doesn't work, it'd be better to ask this as a new question instead of using the comments further

Comment: Actually it worked. Thanks for your help!!! +9000! :D